# Disable title bar in non full window mode in Unity Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity

I really love Ubuntu with Unity, especially top bar - it really saves space. But it drives me mad, when I work with many windows. Every windows has its own title bar which wastes space.

How to disable title bar in non full window mode?

Comment: Sounds like you'd be interested in using gnome shell.

Comment: I'm really happy with integration of menus with the "top bar", auto hiding launch panel and so on... I'm afraid that gnome doesn't provide me all that.

Comment: Not possible. It's the window decoration which is built-in to unity so you can not remove it. Also wasting what space?, it's 24px on a window, not 24px times however many windows are open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity integrated-menus true
```

It will set application menu on title bar.

Instead, if you want to have all applications menu on the top bar change `true` value to `false`.

---

**Update:** if you are not confident with command line, you can use the graphic interface:
open to `System Settings`, then select `Appearance`, select `Behavior` tab and you can change the option you are looking for in the `Show the menus for a window` area.

[image: appearance settings]

Comment: I think the objective is to remove the title bar, not add the menus to the title bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but @WinEunuuchs2Unix is right, I would love to remove tittle bar, I'm really happy with menus is "top bar".

Comment: @Saczew Sorry for my misunderstanding of your question. If I'll find a good solution, I will update my answer. However, at the moment, I didn't find anything that can solve your issue with Unity.